# route info in mapkit in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, mapkit

I want to write some information in the navigation bar about a route..just as the default application does, like distance between the current location and the selected destination, direction etc.

How would i know when a certain pin is clicked as to provide the respective info.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

When you implement MKAnotationView there is a method:

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
```

As far as I understand, it is being called exactly when you want it to.